# Click event not works with buttons, generated by JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, magento-2.3

When I select `"Keyboard layout"` it generate buttons using js - but click event not works with dynamic generated buttons. I think, it is because when document ready, element "`.prices-tier`" not exist. It generates, only when i select layout.

[image]

Part of my code:

```
    require(['jquery'], function(){
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        const currencySymbol = jQuery('.price').text()[0];
        var standartPrice = Number(jQuery('.price-wrapper').attr('data-price-amount'));



        jQuery('.prices-tier').on('click','.btn', function () {
            var quantity = Number(jQuery(this).attr("data-qty"));
            var price = jQuery(this).attr("data-amount");
            jQuery('.qty-default').val(quantity);
            jQuery('#product-price-'+"<?php echo $_product->getId();?>"+' .price').html(currencySymbol+price);
            // jQuery('.product-info-main>div>.price-box>.price-container>.price-wrapper>.price').html(currencySymbol+price);
            jQuery('.qty-default').trigger('input');
        }
        );
```

Generated html elements:

```
<div class="prices-tier items w-75 btn-group">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light border border-bottom-0 border-top-0 bg-primary" data-qty="25" data-amount="27.21" onclick="">

        4%</button>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light border border-bottom-0 border-top-0 bg-primary" data-qty="50" data-amount="26.5" onclick="">

        6%</button>
</div>
```

Comment: [Delegate your events](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) and attach your listener to a parent (that exists in the DOM already) or `document`. That way events can bubble up from new elements and be caught by the listener.

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.prices-tier .btn', function () {
```

Note, this isn't just a jQuery trick, this is how JS events work. For example, it's also useful in instances where you have, for example, a list of items (1000) but you don't want to add an event listener to each one. You attach one event listener to the parent container (a `<ul>` perhaps), and that can catch all the events that bubble up from its children and process them.